# Using ntheorem's counter inside theorem statement

Tags: theorems, counters, ntheorem

I'm using `ntheorem` package and I would like to use the theorem's counter within the theorem's statement. This is useful when you're defining a special object you wish to reference elsewhere, like:

```
\begin{theorem}
     For every foo, there exists a bar_\thcounter such that blah. 
\end{theorem}
```

Since the text has more than one bar defined, I wan't this particular one to be "bar_{1.1.2}" if the theorem is named as "Theorem 1.1.2".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The counter associated to a structure defined with `\newtheorem{<env-name>}{<doc-name>}` is named `<env-name>`, so you can use `\the<env-name>` (for the string including possible prefixes if the counter has been subordinated to another counter) or `\number\value{<env-name>}` (for just the value of the counter):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\begin{theorem}
     For every foo, there exists a bar\textunderscore\thetheorem\ such that blah. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, would be to use the `\label`, `\ref` mechanism:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:test}
     For every foo, there exists a bar\textunderscore\ref{thm:test} such that blah. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Notice the use of `\textunderscore` instead of simply `_` which outside math mode will produce an error.